# JQGrid Custom Button Library

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

There are many JQGrid in my application and each has same kind of custom buttons. So i want to create a CS (asp.net) class which includes all the functionality for the custom buttons and want to call those functions for all the JQGrid's in the application. I am not getting the proper idea to do it!! Any suggested links or any ideas would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry mate, you'll need to give some code or something. This question is a bit unclear. How about an example of how your current implementation looks?

Answer (score 1):

Create one class and implement generalize method in it then you can use it by adding reference using it.